# How to know test is skipped due to failed configuration or skipped configuration

Tags: testng

How do i know my test has skipped due to failed/skipped configuration error.
I am trying to get information in my 'SuiteListener' from 'ITestResult testResult'

In current version of TestNg if my test is skipped due to configuration error, when i try to get throwable of my test its showing null;

```
testResult.getThrowable()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `result.getMethod().isTestMethod()` to check whether it is a test method's failure or a configuration error.